# Numba KeyError with Python3.4, `KeyError: "Does not support option: 'arg_types'"`

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba, keyerror

I am converting from Python2.7 `numba` code into Python3.4. This function `pairwise_distance` converts the distance matrix from a multidimensional array `X` and `Y`.

However, I use a `numba` decorator `@jit` to speed up the code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import double
from numba.decorators import jit

@jit(arg_types = [double[:,:], double[:,:]])
def pairwise_distance(X, D):
    M = X.shape[0]
    N = X.shape[1]
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(M):
            d = 0.0
            for k in range(N):
                tmp = X[i, k] - X[j, k]
                d += tmp * tmp
            D[i, j] = np.sqrt(d)

# calculate the pairwise distance between X and Y

X = np.random.random((1000, 3))
Y = np.empty((1000, 1000))
pairwise_distance(X, Y)
```

This outputs the following error:

```
KeyError: "Does not support option: 'arg_types'"
```

I am not entirely sure what this error means, or how one translates this from Python2.7 to be compatible with Python3.4

This is the error in full:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/targets/options.py in from_dict(self, dic)
     15             try:
---> 16                 ctor = self.OPTIONS[k]
     17             except KeyError:

KeyError: 'arg_types'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-2c486d04f659> in <module>()
     19 X = np.random.random((1000, 3))
     20 Y = np.empty((1000, 1000))
---> 21 pairwise_numba(X, Y)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    286             else:
    287                 real_args.append(self.typeof_pyval(a))
--> 288         return self.compile(tuple(real_args))
    289 
    290     def inspect_llvm(self, signature=None):

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py in compile(self, sig)
    504 
    505             self._cache_misses[sig] += 1
--> 506             cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
    507             self.add_overload(cres)
    508             self._cache.save_overload(sig, cres)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py in compile(self, args, return_type)
     76     def compile(self, args, return_type):
     77         flags = compiler.Flags()
---> 78         self.targetdescr.options.parse_as_flags(flags, self.targetoptions)
     79 
     80         impl = self._get_implementation(args, {})

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/targets/options.py in parse_as_flags(cls, flags, options)
     24     def parse_as_flags(cls, flags, options):
     25         opt = cls()
---> 26         opt.from_dict(options)
     27         opt.set_flags(flags)
     28         return flags

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/targets/options.py in from_dict(self, dic)
     17             except KeyError:
     18                 fmt = "Does not support option: '%s'"
---> 19                 raise KeyError(fmt % k)
     20             else:
     21                 self.values[k] = ctor(v)

KeyError: "Does not support option: 'arg_types'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use `argtypes` instead of `arg_types`, instead of getting a `KeyError`, I get a deprecation warning saying to use `signature` instead.

The following worked for me using python 3.5 and numba 0.25.0

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit('void(double[:,:], double[:,:])')
def pairwise_distance(X, D):
    M = X.shape[0]
    N = X.shape[1]
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(M):
            d = 0.0
            for k in range(N):
                tmp = X[i, k] - X[j, k]
                d += tmp * tmp
            D[i, j] = np.sqrt(d)

# calculate the pairwise distance between X and Y

X = np.random.random((1000, 3))
Y = np.empty((1000, 1000))
pairwise_distance(X, Y)
```

Comment: Could you explain why you are using 'void' instead of 'argtypes'?

Comment: You function doesn't return anything so `void` is the return type. `argtypes` is deprecated. In fact, my recommendation is to just use `@jit` or `@jit(nopython=True)` /`@njit` and let numba do the type inference on the input and output types.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!